# Input is out of range while using haversine formula

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, haversine

I am trying to calculate the distance between several users based on their long/lat.
I am using Spring JPA and PostgreSQL.

This is my Repository-class:

```
public interface UserWithCoordinateRepository extends JpaRepository<UserWithCoordinate, UUID> {

String HAVERSINE_FORMULA = "(6371 * acos(cos(radians(?2)) * cos(radians(uwc.latitude)) *" +
    " cos(radians(uwc.longitude) - radians(?1)) + sin(radians(?2)) * sin(radians(uwc.latitude))))";

@Query("SELECT uwc FROM UserWithCoordinate uwc WHERE " + HAVERSINE_FORMULA + " < ?3 ORDER BY " + HAVERSINE_FORMULA + " DESC")
List<UserWithCoordinate> findByCoordinates(double longitude, double latitude, double distance, Pageable pageable);
}
```

But I keep getting this error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: Input is out of range!

I already went through these articles:

- [postgresql: input is out of range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56146725/postgresql-input-is-out-of-range)
- [Spring Query: Haversine formula with pageable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576674/spring-query-haversine-formula-with-pageable)

But I am not able to fix my issue.

Comment: What values are you giving the parameters when you get the error?

Comment: 48.297329 for latitude, 11.623280 for longitude and 66.0000 for distance

Answer (score 0):

I found another formula that works as expected:

```
111.045* DEGREES(ACOS(LEAST(1.0, COS(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * COS(RADIANS(latitude))
             * COS(RADIANS(longpoint) - RADIANS(longitude))
             + SIN(RADIANS(latpoint))
             * SIN(RADIANS(latitude)))))
```

Maybe someone will find it useful :)